# End the session in ASP.NET MVC explicitly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my project, if the system is idle for 10 minutes, then I want to explicitly end the session of the user who has been currently logged in. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Do you want to logout the user or just kill the user's session?

Comment: @ramiramilu I just want to kill the user's session automatically if the system is idle.

Comment: Then @PranayRana's solution will work. If you need to reset auth, then you need to set `timeout` at `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="28" />` in authentication tag.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via web.config file , following is example of it

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: My code has 2 parts. One is client and other is service. Both the parts contain web.config. Where should I add this? In client's web.config or service's web.config?

Comment: @PSriharsha - this will go in root web.config it you don't have I think you should update both